# Server does not complete booting from Installation DVD

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, installation

I want to downgrade a new Server with preinstalled Windows Server 2012 to Windows Server 2008 R2. I would like to do it by booting from the DVD and not by starting setup from the running 2012.

I go to the boot menu, select the DVD drive and and it starts booting from DVD. I can watch a grey bar at the bottom of the screen "Windows is loading files". When this finished it continues to the "Starting Windows" screen, but then, after a few seconds, the screen goes black and the monitor turns off. The Server hardware seems to be still running, HDDs showing activity (DVD not).

Has anyone an idea, what could be the cause that it does not boot successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, wrong title, booting was successful it was just the video output that was not working.

The reason is that Windows 2008R2 does not support UEFI GOP (Graphics Output Protocol), so that as soon as the graphic is handed over to the operating system the screen turns black.

There was an bios entry

> Load Legacy Video Option ROM

that was disabled. Enabled it and got the video output from my Windows 2008R2.